# MapThread and AssociateTo

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, map

I am attempting to add a key-value pair to a list of associations, but am having trouble.

***Minimal Example:***
Given the list `{<| a->1 |>, <| a->2 |>}` I would like to add a 'b' key to each association resulting in the final list `{<| a->1, b->1 |>, <| a->2, b->2 |>}`. With the a and b values not necessarily equal within an association.

I have attempted this using `MapThread`

```
MapThread[AssociateTo, {{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 2|>}, {"b" -> 0, "b" -> 1}} ]
```

But receive the error `AssociateTo::rvalue: <|a->1|> is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Bonus:***
Ultimately I would like the 'b' value to be a function of the 'a' value -- E.g. `b -> a^2 + 3`.

Thanks!

***Edit:***
I have solved the issue using `Table`

```
Table[AssociateTo[assoc, "b" -> Function[assoc["a"]^2 + 3] ], {assoc, assocList} ]
```

But would still like to know why `MapThread`gives an error out of curiosity.

Comment: Use `Append` instead of `AssociateTo`. Use something like `MapThread[Append, {assocs, f /@ assocs}]` where `f` is a function that takes an association and generates a rule `b -> value` corresponding to that  association.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Append` or `Association` instead of `AssociateTo`.

```
MapThread[Append, {{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 2|>}, {"b" -> 0, "b" -> 1}}]
```

`AssociateTo` is the analogue of `AppendTo`: its argument must be a variable that it will modify. `Append` (and `Association`) do not modify their argument.  Instead they return a new value.

Comment: I am puzzled.  What does `AssociateTo` do that `AppendTo` does not?  And if there is differentiating functionality, then why offer `AssociateTo` as an analog of `AppendTo` but not `Associate` as an analog of `Append`?

Comment: @Alan I was confused about this too until recently. `AssociateTo` is to `Association` as `AppendTo` is to `Append`.  As for the difference, compare `Append[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, "a" -> 3]` and `Association[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, "a" -> 3]`.  Key ordering will be different. (There are of course other differences, but those are easy to see and boring to talk about: like `AssociateTo`/`Association` also taking a *list* of keys as second arguments.)

Comment: Should I be able to cull from the `Association` docs this usage (first argument an association, followed by the updates, which may include associations)?

Comment: @Alan I don't know. There's a feedback link at the bottom of every online doc page ...